# Build Login logic with error message "False username. Try again"

Tags: java, swing, authentication, desktop-application

I have build a simple login logic in Java and Swing. The goal is to share this Desktop application with my colleagues for a CTF challenge. Therefore I want to create an error message "false username" or "username does not exist" when the username is not existent in the database.

I have the following code for my action listener till now:

```
@Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String email = tfEmail.getText();
                String password = String.valueOf(pfPassword.getPassword());           


                User user = getAuthenticatedUser(email, password);

        
                // MainFrame will be created when we click on the "Login" button
                if (user != null) {
                    MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();
                    mainFrame.initialize(user);
                    dispose();
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoginForm.this, 
                            "Email or Password Invalid", 
                            "Try again", 
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } 
            }
```

And this is my getAuthenticatedUser method:

```
 private User getAuthenticatedUser(String email, String password) {
        User user = null; 
        //http://localhost:8888/index.php?route=/sql&pos=0&db=mystore&table=users
        final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/MyStore?serverTimezone=UTC";
        final String USERNAME = "root";
        final String PASSWORD = "root";

        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=? AND password=?";
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, email);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, password);

            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            if (resultSet.next()) {
                user = new User();
                user.name = resultSet.getString("name");
                user.email = resultSet.getString("email");
                user.phone = resultSet.getString("phone");
                user.address = resultSet.getString("address");
                user.password = resultSet.getString("password");
            }

            preparedStatement.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Database connection failed!");
        }

        return user;
    }
```

Now I do not know how to modify my code in order to just check the username, because with this logic when a user is not null, then the user is found in the database and already authenticated. But when user is null, automatically the user is not authenticated and I cannot check the usernames because I got the following message: "Cannot read field "email" because "user" is null".

Can anyone help please? I would appreciate it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Break your SQL code up into separate connection, query, and disconnection methods.   The SQL query `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?` will return a password value if the email is in the database.  Then you can simply compare the input password with the database password.